# How to translate чё вытворяет?

Tags: сленг

Would a good (American) English equivalent of "Чё вытворяет?" be "What is he up to?" or "What's up with him?" What's the connotation, exactly?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth and welcome to Russian SE.  Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here - it's not about Russian language at all but rather about searching for some exact equivalent of some Russian phrase which meaning is pretty clear to OP. You can try your luck at English SE, however, to make it on-topic there, it needs editing.

Comment: It is a shorten version of "[смотри ,] что [он/она/оно] вытворяет!"

Comment: @shabunc This quite obviously does not belong on English SE. The intent of the question was to find out the precise nuance of this common but nonstandard expression. How else should that be phrased on an English-language SE about a non-English language?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning sometimes people are asking about counterparts of phrases in foreign languages. Even if it's not on-topic there, it's definitely still off-topic here. It's not about Russian language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering the slight grammatical incorrectness and casualness of the original Russian phrase, I would suggest something along the lines of: "the hell is he doing?"

Although the exact meaning and translation are certainly subject to context.